# Div arrangement HTML / CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to arrange the layout of my homepage. What I would like is my div #welcome to be the center with four other divs straddling either side 2&2. This website has a good example of what I'm shooting for. What I have right now is the 5 divs working and fitting relatively well except that they don't arrange properly. I know that the order I call the divs in the HTML will change the order they appear but when I re-arrange it they get jumbled.

When I have the HTML like this I get one on the left of #welcome and three on the right (pic below):

```
<div id = "HomeMain">
        <div id = "Entertainment">
            <img src="images/Entertainment1.jpg" id="EntSlide" width=185 height=95/>
        </div>
        <div id="welcome">
            <p>Finest Booze around, come taste for yourself Home to many of Toronto's hottest designer boutiques, unique cafes, artisan shops, breathtaking art galleries, performance venues and award-winning restaurants, The Distillery District is the place to see and be seen. An internationally acclaimed pedestrian-only village, The Distillery features more than 70 ground-floor cultural and retail establishments in the restored red brick, Victorian-era buildings of the renowned Gooderham & Worts whiskey distillery. One of Canada's hottest tourist attractions, centrally-located and just a short walk from downtown Toronto there is always something happening at The Distillery.</p>
            <div class = "Oldman"></div> 
        </div>
        <div id = "Community">
            <img src="images/Victoria1.jpg" id="ComSlide" width=185 height=95/>
        </div>
        <div id = "Events">
            <img src="images/Events1.jpg" id="EventSlide" width=185 height=95/>
        </div>
        <div id = "Distillery">
            <img src="images/Distillery1.jpg" id="DistSlide" width=185 height=95/>
        </div>
</div>
```

[image: right]

When I put the HTML like this I get the #welcome on the right and the other four on the left (pic below)

```
<div id = "HomeMain">
        <div id = "Entertainment">
            <img src="images/Entertainment1.jpg" id="EntSlide" width=185 height=95/>
        </div>
        <div id = "Community">
            <img src="images/Victoria1.jpg" id="ComSlide" width=185 height=95/>
        </div>
        <div id="welcome">
            <p>Finest Booze around, come taste for yourself Home to many of Toronto's hottest designer boutiques, unique cafes, artisan shops, breathtaking art galleries, performance venues and award-winning restaurants, The Distillery District is the place to see and be seen. An internationally acclaimed pedestrian-only village, The Distillery features more than 70 ground-floor cultural and retail establishments in the restored red brick, Victorian-era buildings of the renowned Gooderham & Worts whiskey distillery. One of Canada's hottest tourist attractions, centrally-located and just a short walk from downtown Toronto there is always something happening at The Distillery.</p>
            <div class = "Oldman"></div> 
        </div>
        <div id = "Events">
            <img src="images/Events1.jpg" id="EventSlide" width=185 height=95/>
        </div>
        <div id = "Distillery">
            <img src="images/Distillery1.jpg" id="DistSlide" width=185 height=95/>
        </div>
```

[image: left]

Here is the CSS

```
#HomeMain{
width: 100%;
float: left;
overflow:hidden;
margin:auto auto;
padding:10px;
border-style: groove;
border-width: 3px;
border-colour: white;
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
box-sizing:border-box;
}

#Entertainment, #Community, #Events, #Distillery{
float: left;
width: 26%;
height: 190px;
margin: 1px;
border-style: groove;
border-width: 3px;
border-colour: white;
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
box-sizing:border-box;
}
#welcome{
float: left;
width:45%;
border-style: groove;
border-width: 3px;
border-color: white;
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
font-weight: bold;
box-sizing:border-box;
}
img{
display:block;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the issue. You need to wrap two of the smaller boxes in a `div` and then `float` those divs. See this HTML:

```
<div id = "HomeMain">
        <div id="left-col">
            <div id="Entertainment"></div>
             <div id="Community"></div>
        </div><!-- #left-col-->
        <div id="welcome">
            <p>Finest Booze around, come taste for yourself Home to many of Toronto's hottest designer boutiques, unique cafes, artisan shops, breathtaking art galleries, performance venues and award-winning restaurants, The Distillery District is the place to see and be seen. An internationally acclaimed pedestrian-only village, The Distillery features more than 70 ground-floor cultural and retail establishments in the restored red brick, Victorian-era buildings of the renowned Gooderham & Worts whiskey distillery. One of Canada's hottest tourist attractions, centrally-located and just a short walk from downtown Toronto there is always something happening at The Distillery.</p>
        <div class = "Oldman"></div> 
        </div><!-- #welcome-->

    <div id="right-col">
        <div id = "Events"></div>
        <div id = "Distillery"></div>
    </div><!-- #right-col"-->
</div>
```

And here's the **CSS**

```
    #HomeMain{
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:auto auto;
    padding:10px;
    border-style: groove;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-colour: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    }

    #left-col, #right-col {
        width:26%;
        float:left;
    }

    #right-col {
        float:right;
    }

    #Entertainment, #Community, #Events, #Distillery{
    width: 100%;
    height: 190px;
    margin: 1px;
    border-style: groove;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-colour: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    background-color:yellow;
    }
    #welcome{
    float: left;
    width:45%;
    border-style: groove;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    }
    img{
    display:block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/67oqxe9f/1/

Answer (score 0):

## EDIT:

Sorry did not understand your requirement properly previously(so removed that answer): here is the demo of what you need
http://jsfiddle.net/j4nrn2sb/

HTML:

```
<div id = "HomeMain">
    <div id="left_div">
        <div id = "Entertainment">
            <img src="http://www.brightlinkprep.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/sample.jpg" id="EntSlide" width="185" height="95"/>
        </div>
        <div id = "Community">
            <img src="http://www.brightlinkprep.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/sample.jpg" id="ComSlide" width="185" height="95"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="center_div">
        <div id="welcome">
            <p>Finest Booze around, come taste for yourself Home to many of Toronto's hottest designer boutiques, unique cafes, artisan shops, breathtaking art galleries, performance venues and award-winning restaurants, The Distillery District is the place to see and be seen. An internationally acclaimed pedestrian-only village, The Distillery features more than 70 ground-floor cultural and retail establishments in the restored red brick, Victorian-era buildings of the renowned Gooderham & Worts whiskey distillery. One of Canada's hottest tourist attractions, centrally-located and just a short walk from downtown Toronto there is always something happening at The Distillery.</p>
            <div class = "Oldman"></div> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right_div">
        <div id = "Events">
            <img src="http://www.brightlinkprep.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/sample.jpg" id="EventSlide" width="185" height="95"/>
        </div>
        <div id = "Distillery">
            <img src="http://www.brightlinkprep.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/sample.jpg" id="DistSlide" width="185" height="95"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#HomeMain{
width: 100%;
float: left;
overflow:hidden;
margin:auto auto;
padding:10px;
border-style: groove;
border-width: 3px;
border-colour: white;
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
box-sizing:border-box;
}

#Entertainment, #Community, #Events, #Distillery{
float: left;
width: 100%;
height: 190px;
margin: 1px;
border-style: groove;
border-width: 3px;
border-colour: white;
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
box-sizing:border-box;
}
#welcome{
float: left;
width:100%;
border-style: groove;
border-width: 3px;
border-color: white;
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
font-weight: bold;
box-sizing:border-box;
}
img{
display:block;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#left_div, #right_div
{
    width:26%;
    float:left;
    border:solid 1px red;
}

#center_div
{
   width:45%;
    float:left;
    border:solid 1px blue;
}
```

Comment: The percentages are right, you have to remember, that OP wants two of those 26% to be on each side in a column, the total is actually 26+26+45, which is actually 97%. The problem here is wrapping.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I was hoping to have two children on each side, one on top of the other so 26+26+45<100 is what I had intended. How do I fix a wrapping issue?

Comment: @nhoughto see my answer below.